# How do I display output variable text in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using xsl:fo to generate a pdf using apache FOP, when I have come across the following issue:

```
        <fo:table-cell
xsl:use-attribute-sets="btInfo mt10pt mb10pt">
<fo:block text-align="left" linefeed-treatment="preserve">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><xsl:value-of
select="BankDetails" />
</xsl:text>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

where bankDetails is a variable which contains entire paragraph of text with html tags.
When I print it as is,it displays html tags literally(such as `<p>, <br>, <ul><li>` etc) instead of preserving the formatting.

How do I overcome this limitation ?

BankDetails is a variable, here is an example of a text which can be included(but not limited to) in BankDetails, the following text should render and not display with tags:

```
<ul style="list-style-position: inside;">
<li>Relying on provisions of the Motor Vehicles Act 1988, Justice R Devdas noted that as per section 147(2), the maximum liability in respect of damages caused to any third party was Rs 6,000, and that the Motor Accidents Claims Tribunal (MACT),&nbsp;</li>
<li>Bengaluru hadn’t taken into account relevant factors before awarding Rs 75,000 as compensation.</li>
<li>Suhas R Reddy’s car had suffered extensive damage after it collided with the bus on March 9, 2009. Suhas claimed compensation under ‘own damages’ from his vehicle’s insurer, Royal Sundaram Alliance Insurance, and was paid Rs 1,18,420.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is `BankDetails` a variable or an element? Please expand your question to also show what (a short version of) `BankDetails` looks like.

Comment: FOP won't understand your HTML markup.  You need to transform the HTML into the XSL-FO vocabulary that FOP understands.  If your HTML markup is present as `&lt;`, etc., in the text value of `sepaBankDetails`, then you have an additional problem.  How easy that is to solve would depend in part on which XSLT version you are using.

Comment: Version details are:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1">, also my FOP version is 1.1

Comment: how can I transform the html to xsl-fo vocabulary  ?

Comment: Instead of `<xsl:value-of select="BankDetails"/>`, use `<xsl:apply-templates select="BankDetails"/>` and add templates for the HTML elements to transform them into FOs and properties.

Comment: could you please refer me to an example which uses output variable with html text. Also, for the entire page, I have one common template which feeds value from mode class  <xsl:template match="ProductData"> and in java model, I have @XmlRootElement(name = "ProductData")

. Can I use nested template to write my custom rules ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178920/discussion-between-ajay-and-tony-graham).